# ZPL ^BC command prints barcode 128 set B width too long

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

is there a command that prints the barcode even smaller than ^BY1? because the spaces between bar is large, I want to make it fit into the small label.

below is a sample code that I tried:

> ~PS^XA^CVY^MD15^LH0,0^FO265,25^A0N,18,18^BY1^BCN,28,Y,N,Y^FD>:130-737021W000-49952^LS-50^FS^XZ

I also tried using the Automatic mode but the result are still the same. The barcode Width is still too long, I saw from other label printed with long data got fit inside the Label. I think the Label size is 200px (2 column label with I think 10-20 gap) from  the model Zebra GT800.

Answer (score 0):

Are the dashes required? Code 128 has a better encoding for pairs of digits. As soon as there are sequences with an odd number of digits or other characters, the barcode will take much more space.

With a '^BY1' setting, the barcode for '130737021W00049952' should fit in 200 px (1"). There might be an issue the bar width. It might be too narrow for generic scanners, they operate at a resolution of 0.01", that's about 2px.